# Is it possible to receive Objects from the JS side via WebView.addJavascriptInterface?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview

Can I receive an `Object` through the `WebView.addJavascriptInterface` interface ? something like:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    public void method(WhatEverKindOfType param) {
        Log.i(tag, param.toString());
    }
}
```

( with: `theView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "obj");` )

and in the `JS`, for example: `obj.method(myEvent);`

I obviously tried that, with `Object param` and `String param`, but they all come as `null`. I know I can `JSON.stringify` it, but this brings that circular object issue (which is solvable, I know, but I don't want to start messing with it)

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should not use addJavascriptInterface if you are using PhoneGap. Please, please write a [PhoneGap plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins) instead. The reason you want to use our Plugin interface is that we have worked around a number of issues with addJavascriptInterface.

When you use the plugin interface you pass a JSONArray to the Java side. That supports all the basic types like int, String, boolean and of course JSONObject. It is the JSONObject that you can store more structured data.